# Not getting the correct Firebase String Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a String reference from a nested Collection but it generates a random String instead, I don't understand why because i have it set up in another class and it works correctly (but that is atop level collection.

I am saving as follows:

```
        String folderFirebaseString; 

-----------------------
folderFirebaseString = collectionReference.document("User_" + JournalApi.getInstance().getUserId()).collection("Created_Folders").document().getId();

final FolderJournal folderJournal = new FolderJournal();
            folderJournal.setTitle(title);
            folderJournal.setUserId(currentUserId);
            folderJournal.setFolderId(folderFirebaseString);

        Log.d(TAG, "folderFireBaseString: " + folderFirebaseString);



        //Collection Reference --> Journal <-- document --> unique userID + username entered at registration <-- Collection for Titles --> titleTextView
        db.collection("Journal").document("User_" + JournalApi.getInstance().getUserId()).collection("Created_Folders").document().set(folderJournal).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess FULL PATH: "+ db.collection("Journal").document("User_" + JournalApi.getInstance().getUserId()).collection("Created_Folders").document().getId());

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(FolderCreation.this, FoldersActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

        })
```

My `folderFirebaseString` returns a random String as wel as the `LogD` i have set up returns a different random string but the `db.collection...`(etc...) random generated string in firebase is actually something else.

In another class I have this set up but just as `collectionReference = db.collection("CollectionNameHere").getDocument().getId();` and this works and gets the correct String. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is `db.collection?` and what is `collectionReference` ?
looks like perhaps you're adding whatever the result of creating a new `folderJournal` that is added to your `db.collection` and that's the reference you're getting.
Can you provide a bit more detail on what the difference between db and collectionReference is?

Comment: db and collection reference are the variables i use to hold the firebase references in --> private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(); private CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection("CollectionNameHere");<-- folderJournal is whats been placed into the document within firebase

Comment: and at this point is only used by myself so i can see the different documents to check that the right one is being deleted and referenced etc... before i change the information to actually hold something useful.

Comment: Instead of describing how you add the data, please add a screenshot of your database and highlight the id that you say it's wrong. Please also respond with @AlexMam

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanksfor trying to help. I managed to solve it with what seems like a little hack.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by pre-generating a firebase string and then passing it to its self.

```
       String folderFirebaseString; 

-----------------------
folderFirebaseString = collectionReference.document("User_" + JournalApi.getInstance().getUserId()).collection("Created_Folders").document().getId();

final FolderJournal folderJournal = new FolderJournal();
            folderJournal.setTitle(title);
            folderJournal.setUserId(currentUserId);
            folderJournal.setFolderId(folderFirebaseString);

        //Collection Reference --> Journal <-- document --> unique userID + username entered at registration <-- Collection for Titles --> titleTextView
        db.collection("Journal").document("User_" + JournalApi.getInstance().getUserId()).collection("Created_Folders").document(**folderFirebaseString**).set(folderJournal).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess FULL PATH: "+ db.collection("Journal").document("User_" + JournalApi.getInstance().getUserId()).collection("Created_Folders").document(*###folderFirebaseString###*).getId());

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(FolderCreation.this, FoldersActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

        })
```